# Insulation between walls of two showers

Tags: bathroom, walls, insulation

Remodeling a bathroom and come to find no insulation behind any of the walls. One of the walls is shared between the shower of another bathroom. I would like to insulate this wall, but I'm not sure about the direction, or ordering, of the vapor barrier.

Typically I would place the paper facing inward towards the bathroom, thus keeping all the moisture in the room and out of the walls. However, doing that would mean that the insulation is unfaced behind the wall of the other shower.

Knowing this, I thought I could put the paper facing in the wall cavity towards the other shower, and on the side of the cavity I am remodeling, using something like CertainTeed's MemBrain which prevents moisture from penetrating into the cavity but has pores to allow mosture to escape outward.

I'm hesitant though as I have been told not to put a barrier on both sides of the cavity as it won't dry, but I thought with a product like MemBrain that wouldn't be the case. Any thoughts?

Comment: Usually the only time you would find insulation in an inside wall is for sound deadening.

Comment: there are double sided (paper) insulations

Comment: @crip659 we live in very cool conditions and heat the house more throughout the year; we are adding insulation where we can during remodels, and yes sound deadening will also be a result. However, to prevent potential for mold, in the cavity, we were wondering what to do in this case. The walls of each shower share walls with bedrooms, so its a two birds one stone ordeal.

Comment: @Ruskes There are double sided insulation batts?

Comment: Would use insulation for the outside walls and ceiling, that will help the most.  If possible you can increase the depth of the outside walls(will make room size smaller) and add insulation.  Adding a 2x2 to a 2x4 wall will increase insulation from R-12 to R-20.  Inside walls insulation will not help for heat.

Comment: Why would you need to use faced insulation? The reason for the vapor barrier on outside walls is to reduce/eliminate condensation when there is a significant temperature difference between the inside and outside air. If you are using it on interior walls, I would think unfaced would be fine. It's what our contractor used when our house was built two years ago

Comment: There shouldn't be any moisture in the cavity of an internal wall unless you have a leak (either plumbing or roof). If there's a leak, then it makes no difference which side of the insulation has facing on it.